# "View Full Site" button and cookie with PHP and jQuery Mobile

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a website, with a main version and a mobile version. I'm trying to create a "view full site" button that does two things when clicked:

- Set a cookie so the site can remember that the button was clicked.
- Navigate to the main (not mobile) version of the site.

Here is how I went about doing it:

- Create the button.
- On click, navigate to a processor page with PHP that sets the cookie, and then redirects to the main version of the site.
- Add PHP to the main version of the site that checks if the "view full site" button has been clicked.

Here is what my site is built with:

- jQuery Mobile (site is built with this)
- [PHP mobile detect](http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/)
- [jQuery cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

But it's not working.

On the index of the main version of the site, on the header above the opening HTML tag, I have this:

```php
if(!isset($_COOKIE['dontDoMob'])){
    
    //its not set so check for device type.
    include("Mobile_Detect.php");
    $detect = new Mobile_Detect();

    if ($detect->isMobile() ) {
        //"its some kind of mobile device so redirect to mobile";
        header("Location:http://myforecyte.com/m/");
        exit();
    }
}
```

On the index of the mobile site, I added the button, and set on click to set the cookie via jQuery, and then redirect to home page which should continue to load the main version of the site thanks to the cookie.

But it didn't work: it wouldn't even redirect. I wasn't sure if it was jQuery Mobile's fault, so I separated everything. What I did was set the "view full site" link within jQuery mobile to go to a separate processor page (like `<a href="processorpage.php" rel="external">`), which has this code on it:

```php
setcookie('dontDoMob', 'yes');
header("Location:http://www.myforecyte.com");
```

But it *always* goes back to the mobile version. I see the main site's URL for a split second, and then it redirects to the mobile again. As if the cookie wasn't set.

I think it has something to do with setting the cookie on a global scale or something like that.

---

Note: I checked to make sure that the process of setting the cookie worked fine, with this code:

```php
if(isset($_COOKIE['dontDoMob'])){
    echo "its set yo";
} else {
    echo "its not set";
}
```

It works and tells me "its set yo". When I delete all cookies and retest with firebug, it always works accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to do the exact same thing and I finally got it working. I used the same method as you did so I'm not sure why yours doesn't work...

On my mobile site I have a button to view the full site. This button links to www.fullsite.com/setmobile.php

setmobile.php is a simple php file like this:

```
<?php
    setcookie("mobile", "full", time()+3600);
    header("Location:http://www.fullsite.com");
?>
```

It sets the cookie and goes to the main site. The main site has the following php code:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_COOKIE["mobile"])){
    (...detect mobile script)
}
?>
```

It works for me but it looks like the same method you use so I'm not sure why yours is not working...

You have probably found a solution by now but if not, I hope this can help you :)

Good luck,
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

Cookies have a 'domain' restriction,

e.g. by default, a cookie for `http://mobile.example.com` is *not* available to `http://www.example.com`.

However, it *is* available to all sub domains of the domain that created the cookie. E.g. `http://a.mobile.example.com` and `http://b.mobile.example.com`.

You can specify which domain the cookie should be created for when setting the cookie. Read the PHP manual here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Not sure if this is the full answer for your problem, but since you're mentioning multiple domain names, this may be *part* of the problem.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hello Jeztah. so i rewrote the cookie like so: setcookie('dontDoMob', 'yes', 0, '/', 'www.myforecyte.com'); and does the same thing. i see the main sites url bit still goes back to the mobile

Comment: The redirect is done via PHP only? Or are you trying to use the same cookie using JavaScript? If so, be sure the 'httponly' is set to false. However, I would suggest to try the debug code again to check if the cookie is actually read correctly on the homepage and (temporarily) remove the javascripts to narrow down the problem

Comment: Yes the redirect and cookie setup is done via php. i tried js but it too is not working either. im guessing the cookie isnt being read by the home page because i do see the redirect happening but the cookie, since its not read or kept from page to page, it auto loops me to the mobile page...

Comment: Not sure I can help you further here, apart from trying to debug what is happening (watch your request headers in firebug to see if cookies are actually sent). Maybe someone else has suggestions. Hope you will find the problem, watching your code, it's probably something very simple we're overlooking